# JavaFX Move object along angled path to certain value

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have no base code or example to start from on this.... Just tossing the idea around in my head.

So I would have something like a slider.... at a 30 degree angle and need a bar or object to move along that path to a certain percentage or value along that.

From my limited knowledge I think I'd need to use interpolator....  But where would I even start with this?

My target would be to give the method a value, say between 1 and 100.  And then the object or bar would be animated to that position on the path.  Like a bargraph, but used as a gauge.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm or that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/

Comment: Just represent the value as a `DoubleProperty`. Bind the x and y coordinates of the object to values based on that value: for example, for a 30 degree line, `x = value * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(30))`, so you can do `object.layoutXProperty().bind(value.multiply(0.866025));`, etc. Try it and post a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Brilliant!  After much research over the past 24. (I got slightly obsessed) - Tried a bunch of the basic stuff and tweaking around I think I'm on the right path to learn this specific problem.  James_D you are awesome.  Perfect pointers to get me started or at the very least, giving definition to what I was trying to conjure.  Kudos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update....

I ended up going a more manual route using some old math. :)
Considering I knew how much the bar needed to move, and at what angle it needs to move.  Sin and Cos are my friends here.

Seems to be very quick to react and smooth as well!

```
           double oldx = RBar.getX();
           double oldy = RBar.getY();
           double  moveval = oldacc + averageACC;
           double angle = -30 * Math.PI / 180;
           double newx = oldx - moveval * Math.sin(angle);
           double newy = oldy - moveval * Math.cos(angle);
           double  movex = newx + oldx;
           double movey = newy + oldy;


           Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
                   timeline.setCycleCount(1);
                   timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
                   final KeyValue targetkvx = new KeyValue(RBar.translateXProperty(), movex);
                   final KeyValue targetkvy = new KeyValue(RBar.translateYProperty(), movey);
                   final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), targetkvx, targetkvy);
                   timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
                   timeline.play();
               }
           });
           oldacc = averageACC;
```

Thanks for getting me on the right path!!!